# How to have a serializer not include an associated table only for a specific method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, active-model-serializers

I'm learning how to use `active_model_serializers` ([gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)). In an organization serializer I have:

```
has_many :nodes
```

So now when I make an API request for the data for an organization, it automatically also sends the attributes for the associated nodes.

For example, a GET request to the show method of the organizations controller, generates JSON that includes attributes for organization as well as the nodes. This works.

This is perfect for the show method, but for a GET request to the index method I would like it to *only include the attributes for the organization and not for the associated nodes*. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create different serializers for different actions:

```
class ShallowOrganizationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name # ....
end

class DetailedOrganizationSerializer < ShallowOrganizationSerializer
    has_many :nodes
end
```

And in your controller:

```
class OrganizationController < ApplicationController
    def index
        # ...
        render json: @organizations, each_serializer: ShallowOrganizationSerializer
    end

    def show
        # ...
        render json: @organization, serializer: DetailedOrganizationSerializer
    end
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks! If you know where I could find a bit more information about `each_serializer` and its difference from `serializer` let me know (I can't find it in the gem's documentation.

Comment: `each_serializer` is used when you're serializing array of models. `serializer` is used when you're serializing a single model.

Comment: Basically, if you provide an array of models for serialization, by default, it will use `ArraySerializer` on that array, and try to autodiscover which serializer to use for each model. To override which serializer to use for whole array, you define `serializer`. To override which serializer to use for each model in an array, you use `each_serializer`. So you could tecnihcally do: `render json: [model1, model2], serializer: MyCollectionSerializer, each_serializer: MySingleModelSerializer`